# How use block as parameter

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Obj-C: __block variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878358/obj-c-block-variables)

In block programin How use block as parameter

```
     NSArray *(^blockreturnarray) (NSArray *);
     blockreturnarray= ^(NSArray * a)
      {
          NSLog(@"%@",a); 
          return a;
      };

     blockreturnarray(array1);
```

IN simple my Question I have one block create and also another block create So how In one block pass the parameter Block.

Comment: possible dup of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878358/obj-c-block-variables

Comment: @Jacques - Already flagged it.  Thanks for converting my answer to a comment.

Answer (score 5):

This can get hairy so I would use typedef's and it may look something like this

```
typedef void (^basicBlock)(void);
typedef void (^blockAcceptingBlock)(basicBlock);
```

Then

```
basicBlock block = ^ {
    NSLog(@"Called from block passed as param");
}; 

blockAcceptingBlock parentBlock = ^(basicBlock childBlock) {
    childBlock();
};

parentBlock(block);
```

---

Without the typedef's it gets a bit noisy in the definitions with all the round braces (keep in mind that these are simple blocks so the defs shown are still fairly readable)

```
void (^block)(void) = ^ {
     NSLog(@"Called from block passed as param");
};

void (^parentBlock)(void (^childBlock)(void)) = ^(void (^childBlock)(void)) {
    childBlock();
};

parentBlock(block);
```

Both output

```
#=> 2012-04-27 11:39:12.798 Untitled[19725:707] Called from block passed as param
```

Comment: Typedefs are definitely the way to go

Comment: How IN block as block return and block as parameter

Comment: Sorry can you have a go at rewording your last comment - I'm not sure what you are asking...